# java ternary hack

Tags: java, ternary-operator

So I'm not going for maintainability or elegance here.. looking for a way to cut down on the total tokens in a method just for fun. The method is comprised of a long nested if-else construct and I've found that (I think) the way to do it with the fewest tokens is the ternary operator. Essentially, I translate this:

```
String method(param) {

    if (param == null)
        return error0;

    else if (param.equals(foo1))
        if (condition)
            return bar1;
        else
            return error1;

    else if (param.equals(foo2))
        if (condition)
            return bar2;
        else
            return error1;

    ...


    else
        return error;

}
```

to this:

```
String method(param) {

    return 

        param == null ?
            error0 :

        param.equals(foo1) ?
            condition ?
                bar1 :
                error1 :

        param.equals(foo2) ?
            condition ?
                bar2 :
                error2 :

        ...

        error

    }
```

However, there are a couple cases where in addition to returning a value I also want to change a field or call a method; e.g.,

```
    else if (param.equals(foo3))
        if (condition) {
            field = value;
            return bar3;
        }
        else
            return error3;
```

What would be the cheapest way to do this token-wise? What I'm doing now is ugly but doesn't waste too many tokens (here the field is a String):

```
        param.equals(foo3) && (field = value) instanceOf String ?
            condition ?
                bar2 :
                error2 :
```

Again, the point is not good coding, I'm just looking for hacks to decrease the token count. If there's a shorter way to write the entire thing I'm open to that as well. Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: Each word and punctuation mark counts as one token. So, for example, "instanceOf String" is two tokens, but "!= null" is three. The main things I can see for possible improvement are the "&&" and the parentheses. Is there a way to put "field = value" somewhere besides the conditional, and if not is there a construct that makes "field = value" a boolean without the need for parentheses?

Comment: You ought to be fired...out of cannon and in to the sun.

Comment: Ternary operators are great, but code maintainability should take a higher precedence.  I feel for whoever has to maintain your code ... even if it's you.  If you walk away from this and come back even a month later you will regret coding it with ternary expressions.

Comment: Am i right in assuming that sometimes invoking your validation also changes state?

Comment: Kudos for using a 'hacking' tag on this question....

Comment: You shouldn't optimize for the compiler (cheapest wrt tokens), but for the humans that need to maintain it.  I would practice writing maintainable code, "for fun" (or try a more terse language). I know you said you don't care, but real programmers aren't going to have a solution with fewer characters, because we don't optimize that way.  And frankly, it's not even an interesting problem; it just makes me cringe.

Comment: Since secondbanana is trying to cut down on tokens just for fun, I think we can skip the discussions about why this is a bad idea in general.  I suspect he knows that already.

Comment: Yeah it's just a short assignment in a programming class that i'll never come back to again..

Comment: @secondbanana: the example you gave is not Java, it's not complete.  Your description is too confusing.  Show me a complete running example and I'll take down the number of tokens.  For a start "String method(param) {" is not a Java method signature.  Give me something to hack and I'll hack it, but this is just too vague and incomplete.  Method returns a string, is error0 a string containing "error0" or something else? What is the relation between "error0" and "error1", etc.  What is "foo1", is it the String "foo1"?

Comment: my bad.. should have been "String method(String param)." error, foo1, bar1, etc. are all Strings. the actual characters are unimportant since every String is one token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(field = value) instanceof String
```

Assuming that it already satisfies your needs (and it thus includes returning false when `value` is `null`), a shorter alternative would then have been

```
(field = value) != null
```

Or if you actually overlooked that and want to make `null` return `true` as well, then use

```
(field = value) == value
```

This can be made much shorter if you use 1-letter variable names.

Further I don't see other ways and I agree with most of us that this all is somewhat nasty ;)

Comment: There's actually a program that grades our work, and counts each string and each punctuation mark as a token. So "instanceOf String" is two tokens, and "!= null" is three. It would be nice if there was a construct that didn't require the parentheses around "field = value"

Comment: I would disagree that `!=` counts for two. It's technically **one** operator.

Comment: hmm i just checked and the program actually does count != as one

Comment: It will indeed compile without parentheses, but you actually need them! Otherwise it will incorrectly evaluate `field = (value != null)`. The `!=` has higher precedence than `=`.

Answer (score 2):

if param is null, return 0
Then make a case/switch/select statement on the parameter. That's *clean* .

Comment: I don't think he *wants* "clean" (unfortunately for future maintenance devs).

Comment: You can't switch on a String.

Comment: if you have "equality" conditions over strings, probably an enum will do the job.

Comment: @mtpettyp: It will be allowed in Java 7: http://blogs.sun.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young - good to know.  It's nice to see some useful syntactical-sugar being added.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young Still it's a switch case... ugly and error-prone

Comment: like mtpettyp said, you can't switch on a String, so it doesn't help.

Comment: and for the size of this program, it would be less token-efficent to use enums

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: if you *think* from how the question is formulated that there will be "future maintenance devs" working on this "codebase", then I'd like to have a bit of what you're smoking because it seems heavy.